# Using Kentico CMS with pre-generated HTML

Tags: kentico, kentico-11

I have a huge amount of content that is in pre-generated static html pages. I am working with an organization that runs their web site using Kentico (11) on IIS. They wish to host the pregenerated HTML, but to have a consistent look and feel on the pre-generated pages.

Is there a way to includes tags etc inside the pre-generated html that gets kentico to process the content to give the standard look and feel for the website, without having to convert the content (potentially 100k+ pages) to normal kentico content (it just doesn't seem like a feasible approach, since the content is refreshed from the source regularly)

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no out of the box way to that. I also agree it is not a great approach overall. However, if someone was very determined to make it work and if you really had to, custom programming could make that happen.

You could create some custom logic and use the Kentico API (maybe in a scheduled task if the content is periodically refreshed). The custom code could possibly build out a content tree that is based on the folder structure of the files (if portal), or build out some routing logic (if mvc) to route requests. Those requests that match the ~/filename.html could then be intercepted by Kentico and your custom code, read the contents of that filename.html from disk, and use it as a datasource type of webpart (if portal engine) or a repository / model (if MVC), then use that info to populate the presentation layer of the response of the final html to the browser. That way you could wrap that pre-generated content in a master page with some level of control of what the header and footer look like (if portal engine) or a shared layout (if MVC).

Again, I don't recommend it. It might be very slow and tedious to attempt as well as have performance and scalability issues.

It could be a cleaner approach to somehow get that content into a SQL database and then use standard programming to deal with it in the Kentico layer / website.